# Parameters to be included in the following rosservice call:rosservice call /re_comm/request_2d_map

Tags: ros, roboearth, rosservices

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Could anyone please let me know what parameters have to included in the following service call to get 2d map from roboearth: rosservice call /re_comm/request_2d_map

I didn't get any result when I enter this way:

```
rosservice call /re_comm/request_2d_map "envUID: 'octomap.octomap3343'
srdl: 'turtlebot_roomba.owl'
baseScannerLink: 'kinect_depth_frame'
targetMapName: 'my_map'" 
success: False
map: 
  name: ''
  data: []
meta: 
  name: ''
  data: []
```

Please let me know what should be included in srdl and baseScannerLink fields.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/74284/parameters-to-be-included-in-the-following-rosservice-call:rosservice-call-/re_comm/request_2d_map/) by [Devasena Inupakutika](https://answers.ros.org/users/4122/devasena-inupakutika/) on ROS Answers with karma: 320 on 2013-08-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The SRDL has to be the complete OWL file content as a string, not only the file name (the server uses this content to compute the pose of the laser scanner to be used for generating the 2D map, so the local file name does not work). The baseScannerLink also needs to be a full OWL IRI of the respective link in the SRDL file, e.g. 'http://ias.cs.tum.edu/kb/pr2.owl#pr2_base_laser_link'.

You can have a look at the file re_comm/src/roboearth/wp5/REclients.java for examples how the services are used.

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2013-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Devasena Inupakutika](https://answers.ros.org/users/4122/devasena-inupakutika/) on 2013-08-31**:
Thank you!